# View port height is not working in bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set view port height to these two columns but due to some unknown reason it's not working as in result both columns have the same height though it shouldn't be. For your information I'm using React-bootstrap here. I'm not sure if it's my bad or what? Anyway here's the code for your reference:

```js
import React from "react;
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col"

const AdminPanel = () => {
  const users = [{ name: "Talha" }, { name: "Ali" }];
  return (
    <Container className="pt-5">
      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
        <Col className="vh-50 border border-primary col mx-5">
          {users.map((user) => (
            <Row className="py-2 px-2">{user.name}</Row>
          ))}
        </Col>
        <Col className="border border-primary mx-5">
          <h1>
            list list list list list list list list list list list list list
          </h1>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AdminPanel;
```

and here's the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogpCg.png)

Can anyone help me in sorting out the issue?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that `.vh-50` is not something Bootstrap has defined [their stylesheet](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css) - go ahead and review it, search for `.vh-50` and your search will return 0 results. `.vh-100` & `.min-vh-100` are the only CSS regarding viewport height defined on their stylesheet. So to solve this, simply define `.vh-50` in your custom stylesheet.

```
.vh-50 {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try